# Why is this an invalid identifier?

Tags: sql, database, oracle-sqldeveloper, subquery

```
SELECT 
    places.name AS place_name, ROUND(AVG(frequency), 2) AS average
FROM 
    places, visits
WHERE 
    places.place_id = visits.place_id 
    AND average > (SELECT AVG(frequency) FROM visits)
GROUP BY 
    places.name;
```

Running this code in SQL Developer, I get this error:

> ORA-00904: "AVERAGE": invalid identifier
> 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
> *Cause:
> *Action:
> Error at Line: 5 Column: 8

I'm trying to filter so that only the places with individual averages above the overall average are part of the result.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a `HAVING`.  https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj14854.html

Comment: `average` does not exist in the scope of `WHERE`. Nevertheless, it does exist in the scope of `HAVING`.

Comment: `SELECT places.name AS place_name, ROUND(AVG(frequency), 2) AS average
FROM places, visits
WHERE places.place_id = visits.place_id
GROUP BY places.name
HAVING average > AVG(frequency);`
So this should work right? But this still gives me the same error.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s This is for uni, and this is how they taught us to do it  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

Comment: Switch to another uni that has arrived in the 21st century ...

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I needed the nested SELECT in a HAVING clause:

```
SELECT places.name AS place_name, ROUND(AVG(frequency), 2) AS average
FROM places, visits
WHERE places.place_id = visits.place_id
GROUP BY places.name
HAVING AVG(frequency) > (SELECT AVG(frequency) FROM visits);
```